# Z-index and link accesibility

Tags: html, css, z-index

I've looked a bit around, but I haven't found a solution that works for my particular problem. I have a div which acts as a background, so it has to be beneath the rest of the elements, and then another that had to be below that background, but still allow the links to work.

The basic HTML structure is this:

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="cover"></div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="elem">
        <a href="#">Link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS is:

```
.cover {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}

.elem {
  position: relative;
  z-index: -2;
}

.elem a {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

JSFiddle snippet [here](http://jsfiddle.net/aniaorome/3G3Bd/).

Comment: I have a feeling there is a case of #divitis here to produce a specific effect. If we know how this was supposed to look it might be easier.

Comment: I looked at the fiddle, and am slightly concerned about how usable this would be with real content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see a reason to use negative `z-index`, as this should work:

```
.cover {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}

.elem {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
}

.elem a {
    color: white;
    /* not needed */
    /*position: relative;
    z-index: 10;*/
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3G3Bd/4/)

Comment: hum, this is interesting, while I agree positive numbers for stack levels should usually be enough, I don't understand why it should NOT work since it is explicitly mentioned in the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-z-index): `the child stacking contexts with negative stack levels (most negative first)`

Comment: @DrCopyPaste The reason it does not work is because negative z-index values ([sometimes](http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/)) cause elements to appear behind their own parents.

Comment: @TylerH Yes, I understand, that it does not work (sometimes), but I understood the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-z-index) in the way that it really should work (though ie, opera, chrome and ff seem all to have this same behavior, at least for OP's [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aniaorome/3G3Bd/))   `"Boxes with greater stack levels are always formatted in front of boxes with lower stack levels"` or am I reading this wrong?

Comment: @DrCopyPaste In that link in my last comment, in the section "Stacking Order Within the Same Stacking Context", it explains it pretty well, I think (in addition to reiterating the stacking order from the spec). Better than I can, at least; I'm no expert :-(

Answer (score -1):

This is the correct answer...

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="cover">
      <div class="container">
          <div class="elem">
              <a href="#">Link</a>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.cover {
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    background-color: orange;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
}

.elem {
    background-color: green;
    height: 150px;
    width: 250px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}

.elem a {
    color: white;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: What's the difference here for my answer posted 8 minutes ago?

Comment: The difference is this one says it's correct. Clearly.

Comment: Cover is wraping all elements I changed the HTML is diferent from the user post.. cheers, I actually don't need the checkmark i'm just answering to help someone..

Comment: Mention your change in your answer, so the OP will know what's it about.

Comment: Your change actually made the final result layout different, by omitting part of the `orange div`, which should be on top of the other: http://jsfiddle.net/3G3Bd/8/

Comment: Isn't the DIV cover the container he's mentioning for a background?? if it is, it works...

Comment: it is, but the sentence does not end there `and then another that had to be below that background`